# Резкое начало и конец анимации Android

Tags: android, xml, android-animation

При попытке создать анимацию приближения и отдаления к изначальному состоянию кнопки возникла проблема: когда анимация начинается, кнопка резко увеличивается и проигрывается анимация, а когда анимация заканчивается, кнопка резко сдвигается к первоначальному значению.

Пока писал этот текст подумал о самом значении масштабирования. С помощью **button.getScaleX()** узнал, что как и задумывалось, кнопка изначально размера 1.0, но такое же значение у меня указано в **android:fromXScale="1.0"** и **android:toYScale="1"**. То есть, кнопка сама по себе определенного, неизвестного значения ниже 1.0 (где-то рядом с 0.75), которое резко изменяется на 1.0, далее проигрывается анимация, scale изменяется до единицы, анимация заканчивается и кнопка снова меняет своё значение до какого-то иного.

Также я указывал начальное значение *scaleX* и *scaleY* в самом `activity` у кнопки, но это также ничего не дало. Так что же делать? Почему это происходит и как исправить?

Обрезок анимации (button_animation.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<scale
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1.14"
        android:toYScale="1.14"/>
    <scale
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXScale="1.14"
        android:fromYScale="1.14"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="500"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:toYScale="1"/>
</set>
```

P.S. В *java* файле я никаких значений не указывал. Лишь объявил анимацию, кнопку, запуск анимации по слушателю и всё.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте запустить набор последовательно (убрав `startOffset` и задав `ordering`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:ordering="sequentially">
<scale
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1.14"
        android:toYScale="1.14"/>
    <scale
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXScale="1.14"
        android:fromYScale="1.14"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:toYScale="1"/>
</set>
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource

Comment: С помощью startoffset анимация и так проигрывается последовательно. Не понимаю, почему это должно сработать. Или у анимаций своя специфическая особенность?

Comment: Нет, обе стартуют вместе, только вторая после старта делает паузу 500 мс. `android:startOffset`-- int. The amount of milliseconds the animation delays after start() is called.

Comment: Для `android:ordering` по умолчанию значение *together* (default) Play animations in this set at the same time.

Comment: Использовал ordering как в вашем примере, но это также ничего не дало. Теперь анимация даже пропускает почти все элементы масштабирования (несколько <set ...  />

Comment: Есть ли ещё какое - нибудь решение проблемы?

Comment: Сделайте и расшарьте демо проект, чтобы можно было проблему потрогать руками. Иначе это просто гадание получается.

Comment: Проект со стандартными настройками, в который были добавлены лишь та анимация, код, чтобы анимация проигрывалась по нажатию кнопки и implementation для AppCompact. И был произведен рефакторинг на AndroidX